Multiple ng-content in component under @if
I am trying to conditionally display <ng-content> within a <div> based on a condition. However, for some reason, the <ng-content> inside the <div> never gets shown, even when the condition is true. The content renders correctly under the @else block, but when the @if condition is met, the content in the <div> is not visible.
Here is a simplified version of the code:
<app-header />
<div class="container">
  @if (innerWidth <= 768) {
    @if (open()) {
      <div class="container2" style="width: 450px; z-index: 15;">
        <ng-content />
      </div>
    }
  } @else {
    <ng-content />
  }
  <!-- <app-vehicles /> -->
  <!-- <app-tracking-data /> -->
  <app-map />
</div>

Expected Behavior:
The <ng-content> inside the @if block should be shown when innerWidth <= 768 and open() returns true.
Actual Behavior:
The <ng-content> within the conditional <div> never gets displayed, while the content in the @else block works as expected.

why not use container queries? Why not solve the issue purely with CSS? Why conditionally create elements purely for responsivness?

From the docs: "You should not conditionally include <ng-content> with @if, @for, or @switch. Angular always instantiates and creates DOM nodes for content rendered to a <ng-content> placeholder, even if that <ng-content> placeholder is hidden. For conditional rendering of component content, see Template fragments."

You facing an XY issue. You're trying to apply a solution for a media query not to the document but to a container. As media query does not work that way, you trying to dynamically manipulate the DOM as a solution.
Instead of fixing your question at hand I going to fix your actual problem that does not even require your attempt.
As said above, media queries only work on the entire document or screen. If you want a CSS query specifically for a block-level element you have to use container query:
@container (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 450px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
}


What you are trying to achieve should be simply done using pure CSS. But I want to make it clear, that rendering ng-content inside conditionals is bad (point of my answer).

It is discouraged to show ng-content inside conditionals as per documentation Content projection with ng-content.

You should not conditionally include  with @if, @for, or @switch. Angular always instantiates and creates DOM nodes for content rendered to a  placeholder, even if that  placeholder is hidden. For conditional rendering of component content, see Template fragments.

Instead use ContentChild to get the data and show it.
import {
  Component,
  contentChild,
  ContentChild,
  signal,
  TemplateRef,
  Signal,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div class="container">
        @if (open()) {
          <div class="container2" style="background-color: red;width: 450px; z-index: 15;">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content()"></ng-container >
          </div>
        } @else {
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content()"></ng-container >
        }
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  content: Signal<any> = contentChild('content');
  name = 'Angular';
  open = signal(true);

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.open.set(!this.open());
    }, 1000);
    console.log(this.content);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
  <app-child>
    <ng-template #content>
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  </ng-template>
</app-child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

People are not really answering you directly so I will :
The first <ng-content /> that gets displayed removes all others, except if their select clause is different.
In other terms : you cannot use <ng-content /> multiple times.
To circumvent this, use a template :
<app-header />
<div class="container">

  <ng-template #contentTpl>
    <ng-content />
  </ng-template>
  @if (innerWidth <= 768) {
    @if (open()) {
      <div class="container2" style="width: 450px; z-index: 15;">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl" />
      </div>
    }
  } @else {
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl" />
  }
  <!-- <app-vehicles /> -->
  <!-- <app-tracking-data /> -->
  <app-map />
</div>

This is the explanation, but NOT THE BEST SOLUTION. For that I will refer you to tacoshy's comment.
